# How to convert the JSON data in array of JSON data in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, angular8

I am getting the response of API in JSON format as show below:

```
{
Company1: 3
Company2: 3
Company3: 3
Company4: 3
Company5: 3
}
```

I want to convert this response in JSON array format in following form:

```
{
  0: {Name:Company1, Index:3},
  1: {Name:Company2, Index:3},
  2: {Name:Company3, Index:3},
  3: {Name:Company4, Index:3},
  4: {Name:Company5, Index:3},
}
```

How to do implement the same in typescript? Any suggestion regarding this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const res = {
  Company1: 3,
  Company2: 3,
  Company3: 3,
  Company4: 3,
  Company5: 3
};

const data  = {};

Object.keys(res).forEach((key, i)=> {
  data[i] = {
    Name: key,
    Index: res[key]
  }
})

console.log(data);
```